# Php contact form, worked until migration. Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

So heres the issue, I have been on this for awhile building a custom contact form. Its works the way its suppose to on my development (Php 5.3.10) server. Issue occurs when I upload the form to godaddy host and test. I get the following:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent. in index.php on line 146
```

this line states:

```
if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $headers)) {
```

Here is the complete script in question:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $commentErr = $companyErr = $phoneErr = "";
$name = $email = $company = $comment = $phone = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name"]))
     {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
       {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
     }

    if (empty($_POST["company"]))
         {$companyErr = "company is required";}
       else
         {$company = test_input($_POST["company"]);}

   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
     {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
     {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
     if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
       {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
     {$phoneErr = "phone is required";}
   else
     {$phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);}

 if (empty($_POST["comment"]))
   {$commentErr = "comment is required";}
 else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);}

}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<table>
   <tr>
<span class="error">* required field.</span>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"><span class="error">*</td>
    <td><?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Company:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company"><span class="error">*</td>
    <td><?php echo $companyErr;?></span></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>E-mail:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"><span class="error">*</td>
    <td><?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td>Phone Number:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone"><span class="error">*</td>
    <td><?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td>What type of<br /> Audit are you<br /> seeking?:</td>
    <td><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><span class="error">*</td>
    <td><?php echo $commentErr;?></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
 </form>
</table>
</form>

<?php //Writing out form to contacts/$email.txt
$fh = fopen("contacts/$email.txt", "w");
fwrite($fh, $name.PHP_EOL.$company.PHP_EOL.$email.PHP_EOL.$phone.PHP_EOL.$comment);
fclose($fh);
?>

<?php
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) // wait for form submission
{

$attch1 = $_POST['email']; // files are named after email address
$file = "contacts/$attch1.txt"; // file location
$subject = "New Contact from form w/ attachment"; // subject to email
$message = "You have a new contact from your form. The information is found as an attachment as well as on your server at http://yourhostname.com/contacts/$attch1.txt"; // email (body) message
$file_size = filesize($file); // file size
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); 
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$mailto = 'SENDTO.com'; // Mail to address
// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: $attch1" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

// message
$headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= $message . $eol . $eol;

// attachment
$headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= $content . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail
 if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $headers)) {
    echo "Thank you for submitting our form successfully"; // or use booleans here
  } else {
    echo "Submission ERROR! Please try again";
  }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am guessing that this is a godaddy issue since it works flawlessly on my development server. Client didnt give me access to any godaddy information and only a single directory access on the FTP. How I love paranoid clients!!!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks Lotz in advance!!!

Comment: Are errors and warnings enabled on your development server?

Comment: What happens if you enter a non-empty message?

Comment: Your error is that the current host you've migrated to doesn't support the headers that you're passing, or at least, some of the data within the variables you're passing. The most common is that `\r\n` is attempted to be used in headers.

Comment: Also, what happens if you change `$attch1` to `something@your-domain-on-godaddy.com` and set `Reply-To` to `$_POST['email']` ?

Comment: I enabled errors and warning on the development server. Still works there. Will try to remove the \r\n from the headers.

Comment: Headers need to be separated by line breaks...

Comment: Why is the body empty? It looks like you're trying to put the message in the headers.

Comment: @Mike He's separating them with `$eol`.

Comment: Variables work fine. My message is specified in the variable $message. This works well on my development server. I receive the email with the correct attachment and message body. and yes, I use $eol for line breaks.

I am sorry I can not find in my headers the /r/n

Comment: OP: GoDaddy actually has really good support, I know they get a lot of flack from the community but I've been able to call in the past and get detailed technical support, they can get you to someone who can help you debug the issue, and it's 24/7 and free. Worth a shot if you can't get it to replicate on your server. You would need to have your client call or give you their phone password.

Comment: Agree Jessica^ (Love the godaddy support!!!) Just wish our client would give us there godaddy credentials. Am about to just hand over the "working form" and have him contact godaddy and have them fix it to their server specifications. Because I have tested this numerous times never getting any errors or warnings on my personal server.

Comment: Another thing, from [RFC 2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822): "The body is simply a sequence of characters that follows the header and is separated from the header by an empty line". You have two `$eol`s together, so that could be causing the error. Headers should not have any blank lines and should be terminated with `\r\n`

Comment: Tried rremoving the double $eol and that seemed to break it on my developer server :/

Comment: hmmm I got a -1, wonder why? Guess I didn't ask the question correctly?

Comment: You should reply to all the comments.

Comment: Thanks Mike will try to do so.

Comment: I will try to rewrite all of this to fit the /r/n ways of doing things, maybe thats the issue on the godaddy side of things. I'm at a loss other wise.

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the `From` header to be from the hosted domain as I suggested?

Comment: Yes I have tried changing the FROM header as a test and it didnt help :(

Comment: @jmituzas was the address you tried actually registered with the GoDaddy account? You need to register it first.

Comment: Mike yes, the site is registered and been active for about 10yrs. Just checked php version with info.php and its the same version as well.

Comment: I didn't mean the site, I meant the email address that you put in the `From:` header needs to be registered to your account.

Comment: @Mike, Sorry about that, yes I actually changed to $headers = "From: jmituzas@gmail.com" . $eol;  as a test.

Comment: @Mike I just tried again, got new error this time :)
Function Mail not found on this server. Not going to beable to send much from there.

Comment: Another idea: Check whether you can use some other mail interface on GoDaddy, like PHPMailer.

Comment: @jmituzas You're not understanding me. It needs to be from a registered email address for the domain hosted with GoDaddy. Gmail has nothing to do with the domain hosted there. That is just your own personal email. It needs to be something like jmituzas@yourdomain.com. (I would also strongly recommend deleting the comment with that address too before the spam bots read this thread and get your email address from it).

Comment: About the mail function not being available, I wonder if every time you test your script, it adds some sort of mail fail error to the logs and if your account exceeds a certain threshold they revoke your mail sending privileges. Of course, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities.

First, the easy one: Some of your EOLs look wrong. The main header should be:

```
$headers = "From: $attch1" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;
```

There are supposed to be two EOLs between the main header and the body. `Content-Transfer-Encoding` should be part of the main header, `This is a MIME encoded message` is the beginning of the body.

---

The more complicated one: Maybe the version of PHP that GoDaddy is running doesn't allow you to put the message content in the `$additional_headers` parameter. The message body should be sent in the third argument to `mail()`. Try this:

```
<?php
// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: $attch1" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

// message
$body = "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol . $eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "Thank you for submitting our form successfully"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "Submission ERROR! Please try again";
}
```

Comment: G'rrr tried and loads a blank page. Still shows no errors. What's up with Php not showing me any issues when I enabled them? Thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: It's a syntax error. Missing `;` on the `Content-Type` line from the headers

Comment: Thanks-Mike! and Thanks Barmar for giving me better formatting :D. That seemed to work on the developer server. Migrating to godaddy didn't go so well. Same issue

Comment: @MarvilJoy add another sepator, attachment headers, and content before the last separator. If you tried and it didn't work, post a question with your code.